# why does VLC no longer work as well after I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS?

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, vlc

VLC no longer handles high resolution 4k videos very well compared to before I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04.

Other software programs were also upgraded to newer versions without my knowledge until after the upgrade when I went to use them.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issue, VLC recommends installing it from snap store using snap solved my issue.

```
sudo apt purge vlc
sudo snap install vlc
```

snap provides the latest version and required dependencies in a single package.